# how to use like in where clause of SOQL for string

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql

for below query like is not working

```
static final String OrgUrl=system.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();

string sl=[select Identity_Provider__c from Org_Url__mdt where label 
like:'%'+OrgUrl+'%'].Identity_Provider__c;
System.debug('sl>>>>'+sl);
```

Comment: Ajay, did you run into any errors?

Comment: We need more info. Is there only one Org_url__mdt record in your system? If so, you could add LIMIT 1. Otherwise, you'll need to handle the return which would be a list, not a single result.

Comment: you can consider Only one record,the thing is the query will work for the simple string ,but if any special character in it then it not .

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `like` operator correctly.

I think the problem is in `query result` `assignment`. You should use `List<String>` instead of `single` `String` in the left side of `SOQL` query result assignment because `SOQL` query can return `multiple` `result`.

use `List<String>`

```
List<String> sl = [select Identity_Provider__c from Org_Url__mdt where label 
like:'%'+OrgUrl+'%'].Identity_Provider__c;
```

instead of using `single` `String sl`

Or you can use `single` `String` but then you should use `Limit 1` in the last of our `SOQL` query, so that the query return `only 1 result`. like

```
String sl = [select Identity_Provider__c from Org_Url__mdt where label 
like:'%'+OrgUrl+'%' limit 1].Identity_Provider__c;
```